Generalised Jensen-Shannon divergence - What is a small JSD?
I am comparing the similarity between multiple distributions based on the output of different machine-learning models. I am applying the generalised JS divergence (wiki):
$$
JSD_{\pi_1,...,\pi_n}(p_1,...p_n) = \sum_i \pi_i D_{KL}(p_i||M)
$$
where $M = \sum_i \pi_ip_i$. I used log base $n$ so that the JSD was bound between 0 and 1. However, I would like to have a more interpretable measure of the similarity since I would like to make suggestions on the choice of a machine-learning model. For example, I would like to set a threshold JSD, and if some models have a JSD lower than the threshold then we can choose that model.
How should I set the threshold? Or how small the JSD needs to be for me to interpret it as a "small" JSD, i.e. the distributions are "similar enough"?
Many thanks.

Similar to most regression or classification problems, the answer is context specific, as there is little point of asking "is my RMSE small enough?". We need to have a reasonable benchmark/reference. In forecasting, for example, this is often a carry-last-value-forward method.
Without knowing your exact application, a very easy and straight-forward benchmark would be say using a simple two-component GMM, maybe even estimate the number of components using AIC if I want a reasonably competitive baseline too. Following that, we would normalise our observed GJS by dividing by this baseline and move forward from there. A small normalised value (e.g., $<0.1$) could be seen as being "small for practical purposes".
The other thing to consider is to create a reference distribution. We can do a full bootstrap on our estimation procedure, generate an underlying distribution for GJS' and then compare the observed GJS to this "GJS null distribution". This can get computationally intensive but, without any other context, it is a statistically rigorous approach.
In both points I mentioned above, contextualising our work is very important. If the literature in our particular application field does have well established conventions (and seem reasonable to us too), just use those.
